# Why is a set object stored as a frozenset and a list object as a tuple?

Tags: python, list, set, python-internals

I saw a blog post where it's mentioned *"Use `func.__code__.co_consts` to check all the constants defined in the function"*.

```
def func():
    return 1 in {1,2,3}
func.__code__.co_consts
(None, 1, frozenset({1, 2, 3}))
```

Why did it return a `frozenset`?

```
def func():
    return 1 in [1,2,3]
func.__code__.co_consts
(None, 1, (1,2,3))
```

Why did it return a `tuple` instead of a list? Every object returned from `__code__.co_consts` is *immutable*. Why are the mutable constants made *immutable*? Why is the first element of the returned tuple always `None`?

Comment: immutables are unchangable. thats why!

Comment: Perhaps the clue is in *consts*?

Comment: @quamrana I'm a beginner. Mind explaining it to me in details? or a link where I can read about it.

Comment: In C/C++ there is a keyword const which renders data apparently immutable. ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) In python it is done by having types which have no mutating methods.

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for the insight. It was helpful. ;) I'll look into the link attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All objects in `co_consts` are constants, i.e. they are immutable. You shouldn't be able to, e.g., append to a list appearing as a literal in the source code and thereby modify the behaviour of the function.

The compiler usually represents list literals by listing all individual constants appearing in the list:

```
>>> def f():
...     a = [1, 2, 3]
...     return 1 in a
... 
>>> f.__code__.co_consts
(None, 1, 2, 3)
```

Looking at the byte code of this function we can see that the function builds a list at execution time each time the function is executed:

```
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              6 BUILD_LIST               3
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3          10 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             14 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Creating a new list is required in general, because the function may modify or return the list defined by the literal, in which case it needs to operate on a new list object every time the funciton is executed.

In other contexts, creating a new list object is wasteful, though. For this reason, Python's peephole optimizer can replace the list with a tuple, or a set with a `frozen_set`, in certain situations where it is known to be safe. One such situation is when the list or set literal is only used in an expression of the form `x [not] in <list_literal>`. Another such situation is when a list literal is used in a `for` loop.

The peephole optimizer is very simple. It only looks at one expression at a time. For this reason, it can't detect that this optimization would be safe in my definition of `f` above, which is functionally equivalent to your example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didnot understand this part *because the function may return the list literal, in which case it should return a new list each time it is called.* and *In other contexts, this behaviour is wasteful, though*. Would you mind explaining it to me with more detail? Much appreciated. +1

Comment: If the function is defined as `def f(): return [1, 2, 3]`, we _need_ to create a new list each time the function is executed, since calling `f()` is expected to return a new list rather than the same list object every time. So in this case the code is required to construct a new list object during the execution of the function. This behaviour (actually constructing a new list each time the function is executed), is not really required in some other situations, though, e.g. when the list is only used for membership tests or to iterate over it.

Comment: @Ch3steR In these cases, it is equivalent to use a constant tuple instead of a newly constructed list object, and using the tuple is more efficient, so the peephole optimiser applies this transformation.

Comment: Thanks! Now it makes sense to me. Thanks for taking out time in explaining.

Answer (score 4):

Historically, this has been a result of Python doing [Peephole optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization).

See [this](https://github.com/MatthieuDartiailh/bytecode/blob/fb11be9c932e1fcb559b6dc5b33782775816a9f4/doc/peephole.rst) old (now deleted) article from the documentation of some bytecode crate.

Under "Optimizations" it lists optimizations performed by the peephole optimizer, among other optimizations it mentions this one:

> BUILD_LIST + COMPARE_OP(in/not in): convert list to tuple BUILD_SET +
> COMPARE_OP(in/not in): convert set to frozenset

But in more recent versions of CPython this optimization [has been moved](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/15a8728415e765f57e37f431f09e5c5821a04063) so that it is performed at the AST level, rather than the bytecode level. The resulting bytecode however should be the same.

As for the reason of why exactly, it seems to be performance-related, but I couldn't find a detailed explanation for why a frozenset would perform better in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ;) I'll look into all the links provided.

Comment: "Peephole optimizer" link is dead.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I've freshened up the answer